# Is it possible to get the data from controller to cshtml? (JSON)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, razor, model-view-controller

Is it possible to get the data of invalidTransferNo to CSHTML file? then pass through a modal inside of view.

**Global Variable for the list of invalid transfer numbers.**

```
 public List<string> invalidTransferNo;
```

**Controller.cs**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SelectedTransferNoDeletion(List<string> selectedTransferNo, string deletionNotes) {
        for (int i  = 0; i < selectedTransferNo.Count; i++) {

            var checkingTransferNo = deletePendingSrv.GetDeletionNotes(selectedTransferNo[i]);


                if(checkingTransferNo.ToString().Equals("")) {
                var output = deletePendingSrv.SaveDeletionPending(selectedTransferNo[i], SessionUserInfo.Username, deletionNotes);

            }
            else {
                invalidTransferNo.Add(selectedTransferNo[i]);
            }

        }
        return Json(BaseVariable.DEFAULT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

**Scripting (CSHTML)**

```
 var selectedTransferNo;

$(".selectSaveButton").click(function () {

    var deletionNotes = $('#selectedDeletionNotes').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/@Controller/SelectedTransferNoDeletion',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType:'application/json',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: JSON.stringify({ selectedTransferNo: selectedTransferNo, deletionNotes: deletionNotes }),
            success: function (response) {

                if (response != null) {
                    alert(response); -- getting the data here pass through a text box or list of invalid transfer.
                }


            },
            error: function (response) {

                alert(response);
            }



        });


});
```

I wanted to get the data of invalid transfer no list from controller to a view. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to display data from controller to view with AJAX. What's your current problem and what things not working? Try `url: '/ControllerName/SelectedTransferNoDeletion'` or `url: '@Url.Action("SelectedTransferNoDeletion", "ControllerName")`'.

Comment: You can pass that from your GET action method via your view model. Add a new property of same type and assign that in your GET action. Read that in your view as `Model.YourNewPropertyName`

Comment: Okay thanks guys ill double check, because i already used GET process. But i think i need some rest of my logic stuffs . I'll check it right away. Thanks! :D

Comment: Just adding the property e.g. `public List<string> InvalidTransferNo { get; set; }` into base viewmodel should work for this scenario, and then pass it to controller as JSON object.

Comment: Ok noted @TetsuyaYamamoto thanks!  I am thinking about that scenario. But my code stops debugging on the first loop and it already returns the JSON Object. Because on my first loop and first data. It became true on the else condition after that it returns already my JSON Object through the view model.

Comment: If the loop stops working on first iteration then implies `selectedTransferNo.Count = 0` and `return Json(BaseVariable.DEFAULT_SUCCESS)` always executed regardless of `checkingTransferNo` state. Are you want to display `invalidTransferNo` inside the view after successful AJAX callback?

Comment: When i used the Get process.    `List <string> selectedTransferNo` . became null value. but in the Post process all of the data from view model that i checked using check box are collected inside of it.

Comment: Yes @TetsuyaYamamoto . I wanted to view all the invalid transfer no. While valid transfer numbers  are executed through Database EDMX Stored Procedures.